# How to remove file permission changes from git .patch file?

Tags: git, merge, patch

I know how to discard whitespace changes of a patch, but I need to keep original permissions too.

Comment: Why not just edit the `mode` line in the patch to contain the mode you want?

Comment: @torek the patch covers 652 files, was wondering whether I can avoid manipulating it directly and just use a handy command

Comment: In that case, I'd probably go ahead and let it change permissions, then just change them back. As long as you're not letting it commit, that is (not using `git am`). Alternatively, write a script that finds the mode lines and edits them in place.